# cypher query using java execution

Tags: java, neo4j

> ```
> Following is the java program which connects to NEO4J . it is not properly conneting executing cypher queries. Your help at the earliest
> ```
>
> is appreciated.
>
> ```
>         import java.util.Iterator;
>         import java.util.Map;
>         import java.util.Map.Entry;
>
>         import javax.xml.soap.Node;
>
>         import org.neo4j.graphdb.PropertyContainer; 
>         import org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction;
>
>         import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.SessionAware;
>         import org.neo4j.cypher.CypherParser;
>         import org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine;
>         import org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.ExecutionResult;
>         import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
>         import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory;
>         import org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase;
>
>         import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
>
>         public class arch extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware
>         {
>         String S;
>
>         private static final String DB_PATH = "/home/mkgs/Desktop/placement/";
>         GraphDatabaseService graphDb;
>
>         private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
>
>
>         private String pwd;
>         public String getPwd() {
>           return pwd;
>         }
>
>         public void setPwd(String pwd) {
>           this.pwd = pwd;
>         }
>
>         public String getUsername() {
>           return username;
>         }
>
>         public void setUsername(String username) {
>           this.username = username;
>         }
>
>         private String username;
>
>         Map session;
>
>
>         public String save() throws Exception
>         {
>           System.out.println("inside save");
>
>           System.out.println("username:"+getUsername());
>
>           System.out.println("pwd:"+getPwd());
>
>
>           graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(DB_PATH);
>           Transaction transaction = (Transaction) graphDb.beginTx();
>           try {
>
>               ExecutionEngine engine = new ExecutionEngine(graphDb, null);
>               ExecutionResult result = (ExecutionResult) engine.execute("START     n=node(*) MATCH n-[r]-m RETURN type(r),
> ```
>
> count(*) ORDER BY     count(*)
>           desc");
>                     System.out.println(result);
>
> ```
>               Iterator<Node> columnAs = result.columnAs("n");
>               while(columnAs.hasNext())
>               {
>                   Node n = (Node)columnAs.next();
>                   for (String key : ((PropertyContainer) n).getPropertyKeys()) 
>                   {
>                       System.out.println("{ " + key + " : " + ((PropertyContainer) n).getProperty(key)+ " } ");
>                   }
>
>               }
>           }
>
>           finally {
>               ((org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction) transaction).finish();
>           }
>           return "l";         
>         }
>
>
>         @Override
>         public void setSession(Map arg0) {
>           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>
>         }
>
>
>         }
>
> This is im getting during execution of above code using struts.......
>
>
> Apr 02, 2014 5:53:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
> INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the
> ```
>
> java.library.path:
>   /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/i386/server:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/i386:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/../lib/i386:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/i386/client:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/i386::/usr/java/packages/lib/i386:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/i386-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib
>       Apr 02, 2014 5:53:27 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
>       WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to
>   'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:placementportal' did not find a matching
>   property.
>       Apr 02, 2014 5:53:27 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
>       INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
>       Apr 02, 2014 5:53:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
>       INFO: Initialization processed in 645 ms
>       Apr 02, 2014 5:53:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
>       INFO: Starting service Catalina
>       Apr 02, 2014 5:53:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
>       INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.39
>       Apr 02, 2014 5:53:27 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
>       INFO: validateJarFile(/home/mkgs/workspace/proj/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/placementportal/WEB-INF/lib/servlet-api.jar)
>   - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
>       Apr 02, 2014 5:53:29 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
>       INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
>       Apr 02, 2014 5:53:29 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
>       INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
>       Apr 02, 2014 5:53:29 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
>       INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/29  config=null
>       Apr 02, 2014 5:53:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
>       INFO: Server startup in 1958 ms

Comment: If you want help with an exception, then you really need to provide the exception error message and stack trace in your question.

Comment: So, can you please provide the exception error message and stack trace?

Comment: also create the graphdatabase and executionengine only once, and keep them around otherwise you don't utilize the caches. still make sure to shut it down correctly at the end of your application

Answer (score 1):

you should be calling transaction.success() and then transaction.close(). Transaction.success() is what commits the transaction. Not sure what method you are actually calling with your cast.

The following code is a cut and paste from one of my projects for accessing an embedding GDB.

```
Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx();
try{
    ExecutionEngine engine = new ExecutionEngine(graphDb);
    ExecutionResult result = engine.execute("MATCH (n) RETURN n");
    System.out.println(result.dumpToString());
    tx.success();
} finally {
    tx.close();
}
```

Comment: This is not entirely true. Calling `success() `marks this transaction as successful, which means that it will be committed upon invocation of `close()`. Also, he's using the `finish()` method which does commit the transaction. The usage of `finish()` is deprecated though so your method is better. As `Transaction` implements `AutoClosable`, you don't have to explicitly close it when you add it to the `try` statement in java 7.

Comment: finish only commits after calling success otherwise it rolls back

Comment: can we use struts for connection instead of servlets...???im using struts for connection...

Answer (score 1):

Your query is

```
START n=node(*)
MATCH n-[r]-m
RETURN type(r), count(*)
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
```

but you're trying to access column `'n'` and you don't mention it in your `RETURN` clause. You might want to change your query to the one below, but that depends on your use case.

```
START n=node(*)
MATCH n-[r]-m
RETURN n, type(r), count(*)
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
```